# Changing port of mariadb in docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, mariadb, docker-compose

I run a number of WordPress sites using docker-compose (and nginx-proxy).  So I can use the same docker-compose file for each site I use .env. I want each of the MariaDB containers to use different ports (as they are sharing the same external docker network).

What I have is the below compose file but when I bring it up I get.

```
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
```

Previously I was using the same compose file without the ports: section and with the port hardcoded in the WordPress section and it worked.

Where did I go wrong?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: ${DB_CONTAINER}
    hostname: ${DB_CONTAINER}
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_WP_PASSWORD}

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: ${WP_CONTAINER}
    hostname: ${WP_CONTAINER}
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - 80
    restart: always
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${DOMAINS}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${DOMAINS}
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${EMAIL}
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:${DB_PORT}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_WP_PASSWORD}

networks:
  default:
    external:
            name: nginx-proxy
```

.env

```
DB_CONTAINER=test_click_db
WP_CONTAINER=test_click_wp
DB_PORT=13306
EMAIL=bene@domain.com
DOMAINS=test.click.tvpp.tv
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=aabbcc
DB_WP_PASSWORD=xxyyzz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I worked it out the db service needed the following added to environment:

```
MYSQL_TCP_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
MYSQL_UNIX_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Where did you find this information? I don't think it's on the list of env vars declared on the official `mariadb` docker page >  https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb

Comment: @DavidTheProgrammer I'm a little late to the party, but it's from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-environment-variables/ - Ben, you should accept your own answer with this information added to it :)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:${DB_PORT}
```

should be changed to

```
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
```

(I guess this actually is what you did previously)
The wordpress container will then connect directly to the mariadb container at port 3306 *of the container*. The `db` part is resolved by docker network's internal DNS server to the IP address of your mariadb container.

You don't need this part

```
ports:
  - ${DB_PORT}:3306
```

It means that docker will map the `${DB_PORT}` on *your host machine* to port 3306 in the service (container), thus you can also reach the DB by connecting to the host machine at port `${DB_PORT}`. It's generally only for when you intend to connect to the container from outside the host machine.